# App crashes repeatedly due to empty EditText

Tags: android, if-statement, crash, ioexception

I have created a simple app to calculate the discount. it works fine when the values are provided, but keeps on crashing when calculation is done with empty text fields. thanks in advance..!!

```
public class Firstctivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button find;
   EditText ed1,ed2;
   TextView tv1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstctivity);
    find=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text39);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sai);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            final double a =Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ed1.getText()));
            final double b =Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ed2.getText()));
            double results;
            double c;
           try {
               c = a * b;
               results = c / 100;
               String total2 = String.valueOf(results);
               // String total2="fuck u";
               tv1.setText("You have recieved Rs" + total2 + "/- concession.");
               tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4169E1"));
               }
          catch (NumberFormatException ex)

           {

           }


        }

    });


}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

try tihs.

```
    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if(ed1.getText().toString.length() >0){

                   try {
final double a =Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ed1.getText()));
                    final double b =Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ed2.getText()));
                    double results;
                    double c;
                       c = a * b;
                       results = c / 100;
                       String total2 = String.valueOf(results);
                       // String total2="fuck u";
                       tv1.setText("You have recieved Rs" + total2 + "/- concession.");
                       tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4169E1"));
                       }
                  catch (NumberFormatException ex)

                   {

                   }

            }



                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to calculate the discount, you call `ed1.getText()` and then, you try to convert a null value into a double value, witch causes a `NullPointerException`.
To solve that issue, you have to check if the getText() method is returning a valid text to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check for empty strings and null values:

```
find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (ed1.getText() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(ed1.getText().toString()) &&
                ed2.getText() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(ed2.getText().toString())) {

            try {
                final double a = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ed1.getText().toString()));
                final double b = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(ed2.getText().toString()));
                double c = a * b;
                double results = c / 100;
                String total2 = String.valueOf(results);
                // String total2="fuck u";
                tv1.setText("You have recieved Rs" + total2 + "/- concession.");
                tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4169E1"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                Log.e("SOME TAG", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using try- catch in such simple calculations is not recommended and may "hide" crusial errors. First of all start with an If-statement inside your click event and do all your checks inside there. (if txtValue.getText()!=null {do something} ). this way it is easier for you to debug and correct your code.

So, just to clarify; remove try-catch. do if-stament and check if your txt fields are not null before proceeding to any calculations.finish you click event without any problem and with a valid calculation.